Format WSDL files using Spotless with Maven
I am trying to use Spotless with Maven to format WSDL files.
Here is my configuration in the pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spotless_version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
                <indent>
                    <spaces>true</spaces>
                    <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                </indent>
            </format>
        </formats>
        <upToDateChecking>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
        </upToDateChecking>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

In theory this will indent all wsdl files under my project with a 4 space indentation.
But the only thing it is doing, that when i indent a WSDL file with tabs, it changes it to a same amount of spaces. The amount of spaces spacesPerTab should set the amount of spaces of the indetation.
I did not found any documentation about WSDL file formatting with spotless, so i assumed it is like XML or any other kind of files that is why i used the formats tag instead of a ˙filename` tag.
Do anybody faced this issue with spotless?
I am using Spotless 2.42.0!
